# How to use source images dynamically in :src in Vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, request, vue-component, vuejs3

I've tried everything I found on Google, none of they worked for me.

Basically, what I'm trying to do is passing an object through a v-for to another component like that:

```
<Representante
    v-for="(representante, i) in representantes"
    :key="i"
    :rep="representante"
/>
```

This `representante` variable is the object i'm passing. It has a `imagem` property that contains the name of the image I need.

IMPORTANT: the images are in the public folder because I thought it would work, but it hasn't.

Inside the component script, here's what I have:

```
<script>

    export default {
        props: ['rep'],
        data() {
            return {
                foto: null
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            this.foto = '/' + this.rep.imagem;
        }
    }

</script>
```

That basically initializes the `foto` property in `data()`, so I can use in the `<img>` tag.

```
<img :src="foto" :alt="rep.altImagem">
```

But it simply doesn't work, neither with the image on the `public` folder nor the `src/assets/` folder. Only the `alt` is displayed. I've tried using `require()` too, but it doesn't work like that, or I didn't know how to use.

I can't find any information on the internet of why Vue isn't able to find my images.

By the way, thats the error I get:

```
GET http://localhost:8080/nameOfImage.jpeg [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 3ms]
```

Thanks any help.

Comment: As your images in public folder. Can you please try to access via `@`. for ex : `this.foto = '@/' + this.rep.imagem`

Comment: @RohìtJíndal nope, nothing works. Only works when using the src statically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to add the images on a remote repository so I could get the URLs and use them, that worked. But I still think my problem is very weird behavior of Vue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If you have the images in the `public` folder (and not a subfolder like `public/assets` or `public/images`) then this would work.

couple things worth checking:

- the filename matches. extension `jpeg` vs `jpg` or case
- that you do not have them in a subdirectory within public (or include it in your variable ie: `this.foto = '/images/' + this.rep.imagem`;